# How to make all samplers in thread group run completely for one user then start with second user in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a **jmeter script** in which I have taken **3 users**

Inside the thread group there are **3 controllers**.

I want it should run **1st controller** for **1st user** completely then start with **second user**.

Currently it is running the **1st controller** **3 times** then **2nd controller** **3 times** and soo on

Answer (score 0):

Since [JMeter 2.12](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-releases-version-212-new-features-product-enhancements-bug-fixes-0) you have a [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) which ensures that its children are being executed only by 1 thread at the given moment in time.

So if you put your requests under the Critical Section Controller you will get the confidence regarding execution order and concurrency:

[image: JMeter Critical Section Controller]

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, You want first user to run first controller,  second user to run second controller, and third user to third controller. 
You can achieve this using "CSV Data Set Config" with "Edit" sharing mode. Please refer https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy
for details